# how to get clear image on Facebook Wall

Tags: android, android-image, android-facebook

I used graph API Json Response of facebook Wall POst Images and display in my APP i successfully got it. But the images look very Blur .. please tel me how to get clear images as like in Facebook

here is my code

```
URL url=new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+hashMap.get("id")+"/picture?type=normal");
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_ProfilePicture)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            url=new URL(hashMap.get("picture_url"));
            bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_FullImage)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And in AsynTask

```
dobackground(){

hashMap.put("picture_url", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("picture"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"/picture?type=large"` instead of `"/picture?type=normal"` to get a slightly bigger picture.

Comment: Im not asked to get image size..my uploaded posts and not good looking.. i seems like a blur image. so how can we get clarity image any code u have plz help me .. thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

While `?type=large` provides a bigger image it may still not be large enough for a xhdpi display. You can actually specify a actual size now and they'll try their best to fulfill it.

For example this gives you a large square of Mark Zuckerberg:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?width=500&height=500
```